# How to extract video embedded subtitle from a video URL and show in a text widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, video-processing, vlc, subtitle

I'm using [flutter VLC player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player) to play videos in my flutter app. I want to change the subtitle size dynamically in my video. But Flutter VLC player did not provide the function to change subtitle size dynamically. So I would like to extract the subtitle from the video and show it in a text widget instead of VLC player's subtitle. Can someone help me to extract the subtitle from the video URL? Or any other method to solve this issue?

I have tried to extract subtitles using [ffmpegkit](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) .

```
 await FFmpegKit.executeAsync('-i $url -map 0:s:0 -codec:s srt $outputPath');
```

This code returns a blank srt file.

Comment: You don't have a video URL to extract subtitles from, so how can we help you? Also subtitles come in two types: on-screen as part of picture, or as text from an external file (_eg:_ is text inside an `.srt` or `.vtt` subs file). If you're not using a subtitles text file then FFmpeg cannot help you. It does not extract text from images.

Comment: PS: If not sure about subs being on-screen pixels or not... Use only videos that come with a subtitle file, then your **solution** is to simply put code in your app to read the text from a file. Use a timer to change each line.

Comment: agreed, we need to get that video file you're talking about

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/class-794a8.appspot.com/o/261352.mkv?alt=media&token=fb8f3710-466e-43cf-a46f-1baf7fd9f811

I want to read the subtitle of this type of video file. More than one subtitles are embedded in the video. The subtitles track can change tracks or be disabled from the VLC player. so I think this type of subtitle can be extracted.

Comment: To extract for instance the defaults subtitles : `ffmpeg -i 261352.mkv -map 0:6 -f srt sub_06.srt`

Comment: This command helps for offline files. Currently, I'm working for an online video player. This command will take more than 3 minutes for online videos (may vary on network speed). I think FFmpeg is not a better choice in my case. Any other solutions?

Comment: @badshahbadmas Are you able to read a chunk of file bytes into an Array? If yes, then you could search for the subs within the bytes file bytes. If you want to do it, then you must use a `For` loop to check each position in the Array. You are first checking for a `if( myArray[i] == 60 )` and then check if it followed by a 102, 111, 110, and 116 using `[i+1]` and `[i+2]` and so on... Those five bytes represent the text `<font` which holds your required text. See it as viewed with a **hex editor**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHLl6.png ... You are looking for those bytes and their byte numbers.

Comment: PS: If you're not familiar with hex (bytes) values then know that `3C` means 60. Flutter will tell you (confirm)  that `[i] == 60` as Integer is the same quantity as `[i] == 0x3C` in Hex. So you can check using either integer or the hex values (just put `0x` in front of byte value to find same thing within your Array). You will need to look into MKV structure to know what those other values mean near the `<font` text (it could be they are "length of words" settings, and expected font size, etc)